# How to export one of R's example datasets

Tags: dataframe

How does one export a sample dataset (e.g., Lalonde).

I am able to run MATCHIT examples and export the output datasets from the MatchIt Process but I can't figure out how to export the source example dataset.

How can a reference to lalonde be made in this type of command:

```
tosas <- data.frame(m.data)
```

I'm new to R.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just bring in the data set with `data()` and then do what you want with it. It will be loaded as a data frame. You can export it to a CSV using `write.csv()`, for example.

```
data("lalonde", package = "MatchIt")
summary(lalonde)
write.csv(lalonde, file = "lalonde.csv")
```